# Open and Execute a Music.mp3 and the Code Program in C using Ubuntu GCC

Tags: c, ubuntu, gcc, ubuntu-16.04

Hellow, guys... I'm creating a game and I want to add a music to play in BG.

I tried `system("mpg123 ./bgm/1.mpe")` inside the code, but, this program will run the music until the end... so, the user needs to wait for the end...

I need to play a music simultaneously while user plays the Program. Any ideas?

I thought about opening the song in a new process with `gnome-terminal -e` but I could not.

THE GAME IS A SIMPLE TERMINAL GAME LIKE SNAKE OR ANYTHING ELSE

Comment: I am not sure if its a good idea to play song using `system()` but just for its sake, you can try using `system("mpg123 ./bgm/1.mpe &");`

Comment: Are you using any kind of library to implement your game? (SDL? Allegro? Something else?)

Comment: No... its a simple C Snake Game... but to impress the teacher, I would like to put extra functions ... This code is simple and without any complexity.

Like a 
`code`
#include <stdio.h>
int main () {

play_mp3() (With Loop ?)

//...DO SOMETHING WHILE PLAYING A SONG

return 0;
}